# iOS client: I can have user sign into Active Directory, but how to access MS Graph API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing an iOS app that needs to read User data from MS Azure Active Directory.

I have successfully followed some examples on iOS app from the MS Azure documentation and successfully brought up their authentication page and have the user signed in. What I get back is some user data in the form of a **ADUserInformation** object.

Here's is the code I have:

```
    NSString *authority = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/a5960f61-0bf9-4bf6-96cd-98c61d30XXXX/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml";

    NSString *resourceId    = @"74cd2559-0389-4871-9904-bc767d71XXXX"; // (server)

    NSString *clientId      = @"c8a956a7-84b7-4050-875c-896aab6bXXXX";   //ios-client (us)

    NSURL *redirectUri = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://XXXXevents.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done"];

    ADAuthenticationError *error;

    ADAuthenticationContext * authContext = [ADAuthenticationContext authenticationContextWithAuthority:authority error:&error];

    //authContext.parentController = parent;

    [ADAuthenticationSettings sharedInstance].enableFullScreen = YES;

    [authContext acquireTokenWithResource:resourceId
                                 clientId:clientId
                              redirectUri:redirectUri
                          completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {

          if (result.status != AD_SUCCEEDED) {
              NSLog(@"%@", result);
              return;
          }
          else {

              //save all of this information into core data

              NSDictionary * payload = @{@"access_token" : result.tokenCacheItem.accessToken};
              NSLog(@"%@", payload);

              //@"aad"
              //@"windowsazureactivedirectory"

              [[QSActivityService defaultService].client loginWithProvider:     @"aad"
                                                                     token:     payload
                                                                completion:     ^(MSUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                                                                NSLog(@"loginWithProvider-------");
                  if(!error) {
                      NSLog(@"YAY! %s - user: %@ ", __FUNCTION__, user.userId);

                      ADUserInformation * temp = result.tokenCacheItem.userInformation;

                                           [[CoreDataStack defaultStack] updateUserDetailFamilyName:temp.allClaims[@"family_name"]
                                                                           version:temp.allClaims[@"ver"]
                                                                             email:temp.allClaims[@"email"]
                                                                               nbf:temp.allClaims[@"nbf"]
                                                                               exp:temp.allClaims[@"exp"]
                                                                         givenName:temp.allClaims[@"given_name"]
                                                                               idp:temp.allClaims[@"idp"]
                                                                            ipaddr:temp.allClaims[@"ipaddr"]
                                                                               iss:temp.allClaims[@"iss"]
                                                                               oid:temp.allClaims[@"oid"]
                                                                               typ:temp.allClaims[@"typ"]
                                                                               sub:temp.allClaims[@"sub"]
                                                                               amr:temp.allClaims[@"amr"]
                                                                               aud:temp.allClaims[@"aud"]
                                                                               alg:temp.allClaims[@"alg"]
                                                                               iat:temp.allClaims[@"iat"]
                                                                               tid:temp.allClaims[@"tid"]
                                                                              name:temp.allClaims[@"name"]
                                                                        uniqueName:temp.allClaims[@"unique_name"]];

    //other code, no problems here
```

#### MS Graph API

However, I would like access profile images, and all the other data. I have read that MS Graph API provides it, but I'm not sure how and where I would put the token.

Do I use the token from result.tokenCacheItem.accessToken? If so, in the header? or body?

Or do I simply hit up graph.windows.com twice. First time to get the Authentication Token, and second time for the data?

I have read a lot of documentation and none of them works as I keep getting the  **Token Missing or Malformed** error message.

My Graph API code looks like this:

```
-(void)getUsersUsingAccessToken:(NSDictionary*)token completion:(void (^)    (void))completion {

    NSString * tenant = @"a5960f61-0bf9-4bf6-96cd-98c61d306f12";

    NSString * accessToken = token[@"access_token"];

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://graph.windows.net/%@/tenantDetails?api-version=1.6", tenant];

    NSString * httpVerb = @"POST";

    //build an info object and convert to json
    NSDictionary * bodyFormDict

    = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"client_credentials",                              @"grant_type",
     @"https://graph.windows.net",                       @"resource",
     @"c8a956a7-84b7-4050-875c-896aab6xxxx",            @"client_id",
     @"XLlZl69aUKiQTo4dpeiprItm+LYbDtpt6e9dn0bxxxx",    @"client_secret",
     nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    //1st step
    NSData * jsonInputData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:bodyFormDict
                                                             options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                               error:&error];

    //2nd step
    NSString * httpBodyString = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithData:jsonInputData
                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;

    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    request.HTTPMethod = httpVerb;

    [request setValue:  @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:  accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization: Bearer"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[httpBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //asynchronous
    NSURLSessionDataTask * getDataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                         completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data,
                                                                             NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
                                                                             NSError * _Nullable error) {

    //other code

}
```

If someone can provide working code sample using objective c to successfully retrieve data from the MS Graph API, it would be a great help.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: HI I'm also trying to incorporate SSO authentication within our application - authenticating with Azure Active Directory. Could you please refer me any usefull links.? Thank you.

Comment: hi clement, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answers in MS MSDN's starter projects and code samples

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples

The **specific project that helped me** is this:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-iOS-Microsoft-Graph-Profile

**As you are going through that sample keep in mind:**

Replace INSERT-AUTHORITY-HERE - the name of the tenant in which you provisioned your application. The format should be https://login.windows.net/(YourAzureUserName).onmicrosoft.com

I have found that
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourAzureAccountID/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml

also works

Replace INSERT-RESOURCE-ID-HERE - the ID for your mobile app backend. This is the Web API service app ID. NOT the native client iOS app.

Replace INSERT-CLIENT-ID-HERE - the client ID you copied from your iOS NATIVE client application. NOT the Web API service app.

Replace INSERT-REDIRECT-URI-HERE - your site’s /.auth/login/done endpoint, using the HTTPS scheme. This value should be similar to 
@"https://XXXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done"

#### IF you  have trouble importing the ADAL framework...

http://shanghaiseagull.com/index.php/2016/05/11/import-another-project-framework-into-your-project/

library can be found here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc

Hope it helps someone starting out...and please let me know if I can be of further help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are having is that the http header field isn't set correctly.  Try this -

```
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", accessToken];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```